# Reducing a String causing compile time error?

Tags: scala

Reducing an Int to single Int works fine :

```
val input = List(3, 5, 7, 11)
def op(total: Int, cur: Int) = total + cur//> op: (total: Int, cur: Int)Int
input reduce op
```

but when I attempt to concat String's :

```
def op(total: String, cur: String) = (total + cur) //> op: (total: Int, cur: Int)Int
val input = List(3, 5, 7, 11)    
input reduce op
```

causes compiler error : type mismatch; found : (String, String) => String required: (Any, Any) => Any

Is String not of type Any ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The root cause

You have a function taking Strings and returing Strings and you try to feed it with Integers. You need some kind of conversion from Strings to Integers (either explicit or implicit).

### The error message

The compiler knows that a function provided to reduce must accept a pair with each value of of one type (both elements have the same type) and returns one value of the same type. When feeding with Integers and expecting Strings, this type can only be the Any type.

But your function is of type  `(String, String) => String` . This cannot be mapped to `(Any, Any) => Any`. The return value is not the problem, since String can always be casted to Any. But the parameter is a problem: Not every Any can always be casted to a String.

### The solution

Convert your values to strings, e.g.

```
val input = List(3, 5, 7, 11).map(_.toString)
```

or add an implicit converter function

```
implicit def lint2lstr : List[Int] => List[String] = _.map(_.toString)
```

The compiler will then insert the conversion automatically, when you define

```
val input : List[String] = List(3, 5, 7, 11)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass elements of `input` collection (`Int`s) to the function that accepts `String`s.

See declaration of `reduce` method:

```
def reduce[A1 >: A](op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1
```

`A` here is type of elements (in your case `A` is `Int`).

`A1` should be a supertype of `A`.

`Any` is a supertype of `Int`, but `String` is not a supertype of `Int`.

Actually compiler error is not perfectly correct, required any function `(A1, A1) => A1` such that `A1` is a supertype of `A` (in your case `A` is `Int`).

Also note that `(String, String) => String` is not a subtype of `(Any, Any) => Any`, so you can't use `(String, String) => String` where `(Any, Any) => Any` is required.

Answer (score 0):

`input` here is of type `List[Int]`

the `reduce` method of List has the following declaration

```
def reduce[A1 >: A](op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1
```

basically, what this says is that `reduce` for a `List[A]` accepts an operator of type `(A1, A1) => A1` and returns type `A1` where `A1` is a supertype of `A`. In your case the `A1` must be `Int` or a supertype of it.

This is so because reduce works by successively applying the operator on the items. ie. the result of the operator for the first two items is used with the next item. This means that the the operator function declaration should be such that the same function can accept the results that it produces as well as items from the list.